# Number of prime knots for crossing number greater than 16

Tags: algorithms, knot-theory

How many prime knots are there for crossing numbers greater than or equal to 17? I can't seem to find any useful resources indicating that they have been computed or that algorithms exists to compute the number of prime knots.

Comment: Some of the difficulties are mentioned in this  video ... worth a watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqyyhhnGraw

Comment: The issue is not listing knots with bounded crossing number but avoiding duplication. Algorithms for that exist, but I think, are NP hard, hence, impractical when crossing number is large. And what are you going to do with the number of distinct knots of crossing number <17  if someone told you that it is, say, 201920202021?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using his program Regina, Benjamin Burton has computed the number of prime knots with 17, 18, and 19 crossings (see this [link](https://regina-normal.github.io/data.html#knots) for reference). The table below summarizes the data from the link:

| Crossings | Alternating | Non-alternating | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 1,769,978 | 6,283,385 | 8,053,363 |
| 18 | 8,400,285 | 39,866,095 | 48,266,380 |
| 19 | 40,619,384 | 253,510,828 | 294,130,212 |